# How to get all the values of all the checked checkboxes and then submit it into form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, checkbox

How to get all the values of all the checked checkboxes and then submit it into form, all the values should be combined into one string and seperated with comma, how can I make it happen?

Basically, I got a a database which pulls out categories and then places it into plenty of checkboxes, and then in the admin panel you choose which categories you want certain thing. and then ofcourse it inserts it into the database..

I just can't figure out how to make it...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$row['name'];?>" name="<?=$row['name'];?>">
    <? } ?>
```

Comment: (1) make the checkboxes have the same name/array name - `name="categories[<?=$row['name'];?>]"`. (2) on form post implode the array - `$categories = implode($_POST['categories']);`

Comment: To make an array, and with each iteration place another array index, and then implode.., ok, i will try that

Comment: Thank you sean, You helped me alot, I have been trying to do this for couple of hours now., what an idiot me..

Answer (score 0):

To select all the check box you will use the jquery. and to take each check box value you must store the check box values in an array and use foreach loop after that you can do what ever you want....like this

```
  //this is your checkbox inside your loop
   <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$row['name'];?>" name="myvalue[]";?>">

  //here we will use the for each loop to get the values of check boxes

   <?php

      foreach($_POST['myvalue'] as $invit){


      $invitefr =  "insert into your_table values('','$invit')";
        $allinv = $db->insert($invitefr);



             ?>
```